# Truncating leading zero from the string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to truncate leading zero from the address. example:

input

```
1 06TH ST
12 02ND AVE
123 001St CT
```

expected output

```
1 6TH ST
12 2ND AVE
123 1St CT
```

Here is what i have:

```
update table
set address = regexp_replace(address,'(0\d+(ST|ND|TH))','?????? need help here')
where address ~ '\s0\d+(ST|ND|TH)\s';
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Иван спасибо for correction !

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the address always has some number/letter address (1234, 1a, 33B) followed by a sequence of 1 or more spaces followed by the part you want to strip leading zeroes...

```
select substr(address, 1, strpos(address, ' ')) || ltrim(substr(address, strpos(address, ' ')), ' 0') from table;
```

or, to update the table:

```
update table set address = substr(address, 1, strpos(address, ' ')) || ltrim(substr(address, strpos(address, ' ')), ' 0');
```

-g

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [back references](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) in the regular expressions:

```
UPDATE table
   SET address = regexp_replace(address, '\m0+(\d+\w+)', '\1', 'g')
 WHERE address ~ '\m0+(\d+\w+)'
```

Also:

- `\m` used to match the beginning of a *word* (to avoid replacing inside words (f.ex. in `101Th`)
- `0+` truncates all zeros (does not included in the capturing parenthesis)
- `\d+` used to capture the remaining numbers
- `\w+` used to capture the remaining *word* characters
- a *word* caracter can be any alphanumeric character, and the underscore `_`.